# how to represent pairplot of a large dataFrame?

Tags: python, seaborn

[image: data frame]

> i have tried this

> sns.pairplot(df,hue="price_range")

> plt.show()

[image: result]

Comment: Do you want to make the whole figure bigger or you're looking for an alternative way to represent it?

Comment: I want to use the same way to represent but the figure must be clear to understand unlike above one. this method is working fine for small DataFrames having 6-10 features but raising problem when features columns increased. it becomes messy